# Postgresql function: get id of updated or inserted row

Tags: postgresql, function

I have this function in my postgresql database that update row if exist or insert new one if it doesn't exist:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_or_update(val1 integer, val2 integer) RETURNS VOID AS $$ 
DECLARE 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE my_table SET col2 = val2 WHERE col1 = val1; 
    IF NOT FOUND THEN 
    INSERT INTO my_table (col2) values ( val2 ); 
    END IF; 
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

For now it's working perfect but I want to get the `id` of row if updated or inserted.
How can I do it?

Comment: Have a look at the [RETURNING](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#AEN81612) clause. By the way, you don't really need a PL/pgSQL function to perform this task.

Comment: I will try it, thnx.

Comment: Unrelated but: don't quote the language name. It's an identifier, not a string literal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is declared as `returns void` so it can't return anything.

Assuming `col1` is the primary key and is also defined as a serial, you can do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_or_update(val1 integer, val2 integer) 
    RETURNS int 
AS $$ 
DECLARE 
  l_id integer;
BEGIN 
    l_id := val1; -- initialize the local variable.

    UPDATE my_table 
       SET col2 = val2 
    WHERE col1 = val1; -- !! IMPORTANT: this assumes col1 is unique !!

    IF NOT FOUND THEN 
       INSERT INTO my_table (col2) values ( val2 ) 
       RETURNING col1 -- this makes the generated value available
       into l_id;     -- and this stores it in the local variable
    END IF; 

    return l_id; -- return whichever was used.
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I changed four things compared to your function:

1. the function is declared as `returns integer` in order to be able to return something
2. you need a variable where you can store the returned value from the `insert` statement
3. and finally the generated value needs to be returned:
4. The language name is an identifier, so it must not be quoted using single quotes.

---

If you want to distinguish between an update or an insert from the caller, you could initialize l_id to `null`. In that case the function will return `null` if an update occurred and some value otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the LastInsert ID using the method `CURVAL(SEQUENCE_NAME_OF_TABLE)`.

But the best way is always to use the INSERT or UPDATE queries with RETURNING Clause.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_or_update(val1 integer, val2 integer) RETURNS VOID AS $$ 
    DECLARE 
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE my_table SET col2 = val2 WHERE col1 = val1 RETURNING col1; 
        IF NOT FOUND THEN 
        INSERT INTO my_table (col2) values ( val2 ) RETURNING col1; 
        END IF; 
    END; 
    $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

You can refer the following examples:

1. [Insert Command - Last Example](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-insert/)
2. [Postgres with RETURNING clause](http://blog.midnightmonk.com/360/database/postgres-last-inserted-id-using-returning-clause.shtml)

**Note**: In your `UPDATE` query, your `WHERE` clause is `col1=val1`. I assume that `Val1` will be unique value, else multiple records will be updated. Hope you know that. And I assume `col1` is your Primary Key like ID or so.

Comment: yes col1 is primary key but how to make this function gives me the id?

Comment: What do you mean by ID? In Postgres the autoincrement number is stored as Sequence name. Could you post your **Table Structure**? ie your CREATE TABLE sql.

Answer (score 0):

The [PostgreSQL wiki's entry on UPSERT](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT) states that `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT UPDATE` will be added to PostgreSQL 9.5. This will allow you to more directly express the operation you desire without resorting to a stored procedure and/or introducing race conditions.

This operation is otherwise surprisingly tricky to express in earlier PostgreSQL versions without the risk of database corruption and/or a race condition. The code fragments posted so far all contain an error in that if two callers happen to want to upsert the same nonexistent row, the initial `UPDATE` will update zero rows and then they will both attempt an `INSERT`, one of which will fail. It should at least fail safe, aborting the query and any transaction in progress.

The [PostgreSQL documentation on INSERT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-update.html) (search on that page for the text "Attempt to insert a new stock item along with the quantity of stock") shows how to do it safely and correctly on PostgreSQL 9.4 and earlier. Of particular note is that it tries the `INSERT` *first* to avoid any races on that front, and if that fails, does an `UPDATE` of the row it now knows exists. It uses a `SAVEPOINT` to ensure that a failed `INSERT` does not abort the transaction.